# Magento 2 Setup upgrade issue: Consumer is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: magento

I have transferred my code to one server to another with domain change and also done database changes which are required but when I run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it throws

> Consumer is not authorized to access this resource

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a custom module that was integrated with back-end. I disabled the custom module.